# some weird behavior of std::make_pair with deduction of string_view

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

```cpp
std::string api_key_ = "123456789-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557";
std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view> yy = std::make_pair("AccessKeyId", api_key_);
std::cout << "yy.second:" << yy.second << std::endl;
```

compile with c++17 this will output:

```sh
yy.second:9-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557
```

while this is good without deduction

```cpp
std::string api_key_ = "123456789-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557";
std::string_view sv = api_key_;
std::cout << "sv:" << sv << std::endl;

std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view> xx = std::make_pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>("AccessKeyId", api_key_);
std::cout << "xx.second:" << xx.second << std::endl;
```

output:

```sh
sv:123456789-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557
xx.second:123456789-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557
```

Can anybody explain? Thanks.
the complete code is as below:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string api_key_ = "123456789-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557";
    std::string_view sv = api_key_;
    std::cout << "sv:" << sv << std::endl;

    std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view> xx = std::make_pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>("AccessKeyId", api_key_);
    std::cout << "xx.second:" << xx.second << std::endl;

    std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view> yy = std::make_pair("AccessKeyId", api_key_);
    std::cout << "yy.second:" << yy.second << std::endl;
}
```

compile and output:

```sh
$ g++ ./try2.cpp -std=c++17
$./a.out
sv:123456789-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557
xx.second:123456789-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557
yy.second:9-5c51509f-8c5c5dc2-b6557
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::make_pair("AccessKeyId", api_key_);` returns a temproray `std::pair` whose 2nd element is an `std::string`. Then `yy` is initialized from the temporary and its 2nd element `std::string_view` is constructed from the `std::string` of the temporary `std::pair` (but not `api_key_`). After the full expression the temporary `std::pair` gets destroyed, left `yy`'s 2nd element holding a dangling pointer.

`std::make_pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>("AccessKeyId", api_key_)` returns a temporary `std::pair` too, but its 2nd element is an `std::string_view` constructed from `api_key_`. Then `xx`'s 2nd element is initialized from the `std::string_view` of the temporary `std::pair` and referring to `api_key_` too, that's why it's valid.